# how to use spring gateway in a cloudfoundry routing service

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

We would like to use [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway) to implement a [CloudFoundry Route Service](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/route-services.html#user-provided).

In short: every request coming in to the 'Route Service' needs to be forwarded to a url defined as a Request Header (`X-CF-Forwarded-Url`). The request can be modified/blocked by the 'Route Service' id required.

From what I see (and as the name implies) Spring Cloud gateway is only able to proxy a request. Is it possible to do something like that?

Why 'Spring Cloud Gateway'? I think it provides a very nice API and lots of thoughts have gone into it. It also just feels as a very related usecase/extension to the whole API.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use the gateway as a route service. Why add the extra hop back to the go router, when you could proxy the request yourself.

Comment: because this is the easiest way to add this functionality to Cloudfoundry without a lot of reconfiguration of the whole routings. Just bind the route-service to your app and that's it - very easy, very convenient.